# How can I keep the content of my pages version controlled?

Tags: pages, content, version-control, repository

We have a WordPress-based website that provides documentation to our REST API. Since our API is constantly changing, so is the documentation. However, we would like to keep the documentation version controlled so it can be matched against API commits. Is there a way to have WordPress pages get their content from a remote repository (GitHub, for example)? Or is there a way to push content to WordPress from some repository?

Answer (score 6):

You already got something like this built in: [Revisions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Revision_Management).

```
// Define the nr of saved revisions in your wp-config.php
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 30 );
```

You can simply grab them by calling `get_posts()` with a `post_type` of `revision`.

To show the difference between two revisions simply use [`wp_text_diff()`](http://queryposts.com/function/wp_text_diff/).

```
// Example
$revisions = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'revision'
) );
echo wp_text_diff(
     $revisions[0]['post_content']
    ,$revisions[1]['post_content']
    ,array(
         'title'       => 'Revision diff'
        ,'title_left'  => $revisions[0]['post_title']
        ,'title_right' => $revisions[1]['post_title']
     )
);
```

To diff for e.g. the last version with the version prior to the last, you could use `end( $revisions )['post_content']` and diff it with `$revisions[ count( $revisions ) -2 ]['post_content']`. (Note: `-2` as the arrays index start with zero and you want the version prior to the last.).

Comment: I like the idea of Revision. And there's a popular plugin [WP Document Revisions](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-document-revisions/) can help managing revisions better.

Comment: @Rilwis Should be an answer then :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [Git hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) and post per [XML-RPC](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) to WordPress. A Git hook can be any executable file, even PHP.

Another option – on GitHub – is to use the email hook: Go to `https://github.com/username/projectname/admin/hooks`, select *Email* and send an email to the blog. Enable the [Post per email](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email) feature.

Comment: +1 Now we just need a combination of both features (built as solid plugin by the OP) :)